# Traducción de "soundness"

Tags: traducción, inglés

Se usa mucho en lógica: un argumento es "sound" si no solamente es correcto sino que además denota un hecho real. Por ejemplo, el silogismo que concluye que Sócrates es mortal es "sound", además de válido, pero

1. Todos los pájaros vuelan.
2. Los pingüinos son pájaros.
3. Por lo tanto, os pingüinos vuelan.

no es un argumento "sound". En general lo traduzco como "coherente" o "válido en realidad", pero me gustaría saber si ya existe un vocablo que denote esta idea, o si hay mejores palabras para esto. ¡Gracias!

Comment: La wikipedia lo llama [solidez](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solidez), argumento “sólido”.

Comment: ¡Buenísimo! Gracias :)

Comment: @aerobiomat: ponlo como respuesta para marcarlo, por favor.

Comment: De acuerdo, lo ampliaré un poco para que no parezca un comentario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La Wikipedia enlaza [*solidez*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solidez) como traducción de [soundness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundness). Y ambas coinciden con [otras](https://es.unionpedia.org/Solidez) [páginas](https://fidesetratiomx.wordpress.com/2015/12/01/validez-y-solidez-en-los-argumentos-o-silogismos/) [sobre](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ugEzr7Aed1I) lógica en definirlo como la propiedad de un argumento en el que:

- La deducción es [válida](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Validez_(l%C3%B3gica)).
- Las premisas son verdaderas.

[Alguno](https://gredos.usal.es/bitstream/handle/10366/68890/Logica_y_argumentacion_La_estructura_de_.pdf) lo define de forma mucho más complicada, pero eso es ya para otro foro.

Answer (score 2):

*Es un argumento **firme.***

would fit here.

**firme**

(adj.) = firm ; powerful ; **sound** ; strong ; uncompromising ; steadfast ; assertive ; adamant ; taut ; tight ; uncompromised ; staunch [stanch, -USA] ; rock solid ; unswerving ; toned ; stout .

Comment: Este también funciona, junto con el de arriba. Gracias :)

Answer (score 0):

El término que buscas me parece que es

#### [**consistencia**](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistencia_(l%C3%B3gica)) lógica

Wikipedia lo define como

> En metalógica, la consistencia o consistencia lógica es la propiedad que tienen los sistemas formales cuando no es posible deducir una contradicción dentro del sistema. Es decir, dado un lenguaje formal y un aparato deductivo (axiomas y reglas de inferencia), no es posible deducir una fórmula y su negación. La existencia de un modelo implica que una teoría lógica es consistente.

En el diccionario RAE, [consistencia](https://dle.rae.es/consistencia?m=form) significa

> 1. f. Duración, estabilidad, solidez.
> 2. f. Trabazón, coherencia entre las partículas de una masa o los elementos de un conjunto

Comment: No. La consistencia es en última instancia una propiedad absoluta: no se deducen contradicciones del sistema formal. La solidez es relativa con respecto a las premisas: bajo alguna interpretación, son verdaderas semánticamente.

Comment: Por lo que entiendo consistencia es lo mismo, de acuerdo a como este articulo define soundness : https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundness)

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/88274/why-does-soundness-imply-consistency

Comment: En términos únicamente de lenguajes formales, 'solidez' (ya me gustó el término) y consistencia son casi lo mismo, aunque la solidez se refiere a las interpretaciones semánticas. Más generalmente, la solidez de un argumento formal (Sócrates vs. los pingüinos, arriba) es distinta.

Comment: La *validez* y la *solidez* son características de silogismos o deducciones individuales.
La *consistencia* afecta a un sistema axiomático completo. Es la inexistencia de contradicción entre todas las proposiciones que se pueden deducir de los axiomas.